# MDI Child Form not fitting into parent form in WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a really strange situation which I'm not sure whether it's a bug or if it is something I have forgotten to do since I am new to WinForms.

Here is what happens:

[image]

1) I Start my application which loads the **Home page**:

2) I Click on "**Stock Management**"  but first time I click it does not show the Tab form layout control.

3) I Click back to home and then click "**Stock Management**" again. This time it shows the tab control layout.

Here is the code I use for the "**Stock Management**" `On_Click` event:

```
        private void btnStockManagement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (f.GetType() == typeof(frmStockManagement))
            {
                f.Activate();
                return;
            }
        }
        Form frm = new frmStockManagement();
        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.Show();
    }
```

Here is the code I use for the Child form `On_Load` Event:

```
    public partial class frmStockManagement : Form
{
    public frmStockManagement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.ControlBox = false;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

How do I get the Child form to show properly the first time?

Comment: *First time* ("shown" word is missing) is achieved using [`Shown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx) event in winforms. You probably using wrong event (constructor?) as for now.

Comment: can you add to that a little more - I'm seriously new to this. So i need to add a shown event?

Comment: You have to read [more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx) (it's important). I see `OnLoad` in your code, try overriding [`OnShown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onshown(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this issue is a bug.

The conditions for this bug:

- Child `FormBorderStyle` is set to `none`
- Parent `FormBorderStyle` is set to `none`
- Controls added to Child Form such as `Tab Control` or `Buttons` (put buttons in all corners to see if the form loads properly. You should see part of the form missing on first load

The work around this I found is to set the child `FormBorderStyle` to anything but `none` and to set `ControlBox` to `false` so that the control box will not appear in the Parent MDI form.

Hope this helps anyone else trying this.